# Django Site Migration Issue

Tags: django, django-templates

I have been requested to move a site for someone from there current hosting company to our hosting company.

I have gotten so far that the site is up and running but none of the stylesheets or images are showing up.
I have had a look at the source code of the site and I do see that it is not showing up right.

```
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<link href="/static/css/bootstrap-non-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,projection" />
<link href="/static/css/main.css"
```

This is a first for me working with Django so I am very unfamiliar with how a application like this would be structured.

I would appreciate the help with getting the clients site up and running again.

Comment: Please follow this link this may help you https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: I did just do a test where I ran in the env enviroment env/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000 And when I tested the site form there everything was showing correctly. Why would it not show right if I brows the site normaly via port 80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `port 80`  will `bind to all IP addresses this computer supports ip address`. So let me guess.. you are into production server. Here you may have to considered `DEBUG` and `collectstatic` ..

Comment: Unfortunate I am not familiar with Django so not 100% sure what I am doing here. I have gotten as far as I have come with a whole bunch of tutorials

Comment: oh.Ok .. you said that `8000` will run perfect ..?

Comment: Yes when I run it under port 8000 it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Ok I fixed it with doing a proxy pass using nginx.